# React : Invalid hooks call without changing the React code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks

I am working on a full-stack app. My front-end, built on React was working fine. I installed cors for my back-end and it suddenly started giving me `Invalid hook call` error in my react app.

I tried uninstalling the dependency and also reverting to 2 old commits but it didn't work. **I'm thinking it might be because of a peer dependency** causing multiple versions of React. I tried `npm ls react` and `npm ls react-dom` but I have only one version for each i.e. 17.0.2.

The error message is also not helpful as I cannot understand where to start digging from. Attaching it below.

Here's the [code repo](https://github.com/sarthakkundra/dyte-assignment) (I couldn't figure out which part of code to share). The React code is inside the client directory. If someone can pinpoint me where to look or help me with the issue I'll be obliged. Thanks!

**Error message**
[image: Error message invalid hook call]

Comment: Try deleting all the node_modules and install them again via npm.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan Already tried.

Comment: can you add the code inside `src/use-id.ts` to the question?